# The solution for Sinh[] and Cosh[]

Tags: differential-equations, simplifying-expressions, boundary-conditions

I saw this equation a book that has two solution: one Sinh[] and another one is Cosh[] but I can't find them with Mathematica 13?!!

```
  Clear["Global`*"]
  eqn = {(y'[t])^2 - (b*a^2/3) y[t]^2 == -k* a^2};
  sol = DSolve[{eqn}, y[t], t]
```

b,a are positive value and k is taking +1 and -1.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the solution? Can you include the full solution you saw to see if it is functionally equivalent to the one produced by Mathematica?

Comment: Sqrt[(3 k)/b] Cosh[ Sqrt[b/3] c (t - C[1])] for the case k>0

Comment: Sqrt[(3 |k|)/b] Sinh[ Sqrt[b/3] c (t - C[1])]  for the case k<0

Comment: Armin, what is the definition for the constant `c` (*small* `c`, not the `C[1]`) in the solution above?

Comment: @MarcoB I think `c` should be `a` and the second solution should/could be written `Sqrt[(-3 k)/b] Sinh[Sqrt[b/3] a (t - C[1])]`

Answer (score 5):

Let `k -> -kk`

```
Clear["Global`*"]

eqn = {(y'[t])^2 - (b*a^2/3) y[t]^2 == -k*a^2} /. k -> -kk;

sol = DSolve[{eqn}, y[t], t] // ExpToTrig // Simplify

(*   {{y[t] -> (1/(2 b))((1 - 3 b kk) Cosh[1/3 Sqrt[b] (Sqrt[3] a t + 3 C[1])] + 
(1 + 3 b kk) Sinh[1/3 Sqrt[b] (Sqrt[3] a t + 3 C[1])])},

{y[t] -> (1/(2 b))((1 - 3 b kk) Cosh[1/3 Sqrt[b] (Sqrt[3] a t - 3 C[1])] - 
  (1 + 3 b kk) Sinh[1/3 Sqrt[b] (Sqrt[3] a t - 3 C[1])])}}   *)
```

Answer (score 4):

If we multiply the arbitrary constant `C[1]` by `I`, `FullSimplify` can do the job if passed the correct assumptions:

```
FullSimplify[
  sol /. C[1] -> I C[1], 
  Assumptions -> a > 0 && b > 0 && {k, t, C[1]} ∈ Reals
]
```

[image]

Comment: why the solution is complex ?!!

Comment: Hard to say what `DSolve` is doing under the hood, but if it's solving as a separable equation with `Solve`, then `I` is introduced immediately e.g. `Solve[eqn, y'[t]]`. This doesn't mean the solution is complex, as the `I` could be distributed into the radical.

Comment: I'm more interested in how you discover this solution in Mathematica. Naively I would think, if it can do it for `I C[1]` it should also be able to do it for `k C[1]`, where `k` is any complex number, including `1`.